# How come a method marked [TestMethod] runs before the [AssemblyInitializeAttribute]?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

In our unit tests we have to set up some configuration every time before the tests run. For some reason, though, two unit tests run before our method marked [AssemblyInitializeAttribute].

The two test methods I am referring to are marked appropriately with the [TestMethod] attribute and per MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute(v=vs.80).aspx) should not be running yet.

Any ideas? Couldn't find anything online that was useful.

Comment: Read the yellow bits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx

Comment: I have, it is not using the HostType("ASP.NET")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was the two tests were actually in another assembly I must have overlooked that fact and I ran Tests->All Tests In Current Solution